expl3 sequence of prop lists
I wished to use expl3 in more procedural fashion how it claims to behave. But I must say, I am disappointed that so easy task like assigning value of one variable or list item to other is very difficult or maybe close to impossible. I also wish to have iteration through the items of the sequence and the code for it is also kinda funny.
My use case is having relatively complex package for writing proposals. I wish to create e.g. sequence of the work packages, which will be represented as a prop lists with items as "lead" or "id". I wish to be able to easily itterate this structure, when e.g. generating charts. I wish to be able to filter them by particular key, such as give me just elements in the sequence, with given lead string.
So what I did so far is to created in the foreach loop
\foreach \wa in \tempwa {
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_work_areas_seq {\wa}         
    \edef\tempwp{\pdataref{\wa}{wp}{ids}}
     \foreach \wp in \tempwp{
%        \texttt{WP \wp}
          \prop_put:Nnx \l_wp_prop {id} {\wp}
         % Get the lead for the work package
          \edef\templead{\pdataref@safe{\wp}{lead}} 
          \prop_put:Nnx \l_wp_prop {lead} {\pdataref{wp}{\wp}{lead}}
        \seq_gput_right:NV \g_wp_seq \l_wp_prop
      }
}

Even here I am not sure, because even if this is valid code, if \seq_gput_right:NV \g_wp_seq \l_wp_prop does in fact g_wp_seq.push(l_wp_prop) I hope, that the deep copy is created so that when the variable l_wp_prop goes out of scope, in g_wp_seq will be still proper copy of it.
Now I wish to iterate over work packages and print some basic properties of the work packages.
\str_new:N \l_wp_str
\str_new:N \l_wp_lead_str
%\prop_new:N \l_wp_prop
\int_new:N \g_i_int
\int_gset:Nn \g_i_int {0} 
\int_while_do:nn {\g_i_int < \seq_count:N \g_wp_seq}
{   
    % I WANT \l_wp_prop = \g_wp_seq[\g_i_int]
    % THE FOLLOWING LINE DOES NOT WORK
    \prop_set:Nn \l_wp_prop {\seq_item:Nn \g_wp_seq {\int_use:N \g_i_int}}

    % Get the 'id' from the property and store it in \l_wp_str
    \prop_get:NnN \l_wp_prop {id} \l_wp_str
    \prop_get:NnN \l_wp_prop {id} \l_wp_lead_str

    % Output the current index and the 'id' property
    \texttt{i: \int_use:N \g_i_int, id: \l_wp_str lead:\l_wp_lead_str } \newline

    % Increment the index
    \int_incr:N \g_i_int
}

Here I am completely lost how to do something so easy in other languages ... assigment :)

Welcome to TeX.SX! There is \seq_map_inline:Nn which might help with what you're after.

Actually I want to know the index.

can you provide a complete minimal example we can compile? it is a bit ... odd ... to use \foreach with expl3. is there some reason you don't want to use the loops provided by expl3? note that your variable names should include a module identifier to avoid clashes e.g. \g_vojtak_wp_seq or whatever.

\prop_set:Nn makes no sense. You always set a key and its value, so the command is \prop_set:Nnn.

why using \foreach and \edef ? that looks very odd in an L3 context

you have shown fragments of code but not in a form anyone can see what they do, \edef\tempwp{\pdataref{\wa}{wp}{ids}} for example fully expands \pdataref and \wa but we do not know what either of those are (\wa is extracted from \tempwa   but you have not shown that)

I voted to close for "needs details or clarity" if you provided a clearer statement of what you wanted to do and provided an example that did not depend on undefined commands, then obviously the close vote would be removed. It's not at all clear what you intend to assign here, but also the expl3 code should not be using \edef or \foreach (the latter is not defined at all here but I guess you are using the loop from pgf?)
